# MVC split row into columns or group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to split my row into few columns i have data:
A - 21 - PL - 21 - OFF
A - 22 - PL - 22 - OFF
B - 1 - DE - 1 - Green
B - 2 - DE - 2 - Green
C - 30 - ES - 30 - Orange
C - 31 - ES - 31 - Orange
D - 1 - TH - 1 - RED
D - 2 - TH - 2 - RED

That data show for me as List (just in one column all data step by step) and i can't groupby "Name" but i want to split it into columns:
Coulmn1: A-21-PL-21-OFF | Column2: B - 1 - DE - 1 - Green | coulmn3: C - 30 - ES - 30 - Orange

Here's my code for generate View where i want get columns with data grouped by name:

```
        public ActionResult PosList()
    {
        List<StanowiskoVM> devicesList;

        using (Db db = new Db())
        {

            devicesList = db.Stanowisko.ToArray().Select(x => new StanowiskoVM(x)).ToList();

        }

        return View(devicesList);
    }
```

here's my variables in ViewModel:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Country{ get; set; }
```

And i get my View of List what i get from database to VM:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
       Name: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nazwa) + Kraj: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Kraj) + @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AktualnyStan)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now i need split it on the new columns when item.nazwa == "A"...

Comment: can you please edit your post and add more details like what is the input, what is the expected output and what you are getting

Comment: what do you mean by `grouped by name`?

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla because all column has name: first column: A, second: B, third: C etc. So i want groupby Name and show data in 3 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't trivial since the number of items in each column may be different.  You need to create a Pivot table.

See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                                  "A - 21 - PL - 21 - OFF",
                                  "A - 22 - PL - 22 - OFF",
                                  "B - 1 - DE - 1 - Green",
                                  "B - 2 - DE - 2 - Green",
                                  "C - 30 - ES - 30 - Orange",
                                  "C - 31 - ES - 31 - Orange",
                                  "D - 1 - TH - 1 - RED",
                                  "D - 2 - TH - 2 - RED"
                              };
            var uniqueNames = inputs
                .Select(x => new { key = x.Split(new char[] {'-'}).First().Trim(), name = x})
                .GroupBy(x => x.key) 
                .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                .ToArray();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (var name in uniqueNames)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(name.Key, typeof(string));
            }
            int maxRows = uniqueNames.Max(x => x.Count());

            for(int row = 0; row < maxRows; row++)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                for(int col = 0; col < uniqueNames.Count(); col++)
                {
                    if(row < uniqueNames[col].Count())
                    {
                        newRow[col] = uniqueNames[col].Skip(row).First().name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to do it in View when name of model change or something like i edited my first post @jdweng

Comment: You can always bind the view to the datatable.

Comment: I changed the <= to <.  You will get an error if the number of items in each column is not the same with <=.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `LINQ`

```
var mylist = new List<string> { "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D" };
var result = mylist.GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => x.OrderBy(x => x).Take(1))
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: @Plejx243, Hope this sample helps you